# Font-Awesome Icons coming as Box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I am trying to implement Font-Awesome with Twitter Bootstrap and Jquery , Jquery Mobile. But I am getting only square boxes in place of those icons.Are there any compatibiolty issues . Follwing is the html code.Any help over this is appriciated. Thanks

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">   
    <!--     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome">-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-camera-retro</p>
    <div class="container fullContainer" >
    <div class="row port-container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <nav class="navbar" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px; ">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="menu-li bg-green box2x2 pull-left"><a href="#" id="resumelink"><span>About Us</span><i class="i-centered icon-attach-1"></i></a></li>
     <li class="menu-li bg-orange box2x2 pull-right"><a href="#" id="worklink"><span>Search</span><i class="i-centered icon-art-gallery"></i></a></li>
      <li class="menu-li bg-purple box2x2 pull-left"><a href="#" id="resumelink"><span>Whats New</span><i class="i-centered icon-attach-1"></i></a></li>
      <li class="menu-li bg-white box2x2 pull-right"><a href="#" id="worklink"><span>Brouchers</span><i class="i-centered icon-art-gallery"></i></a></li>
      <li class="menu-li bg-red box2x2 pull-left"><a href="#" id="lifelink"><span>Favourites</span><i class="i-centered icon-pitch"></i></a></li>
      <li class="menu-li bg-blue box2x2 pull-right"><a href="#" id="contactlink"><span>Contact Us</span><i class="i-centered icon-email"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes. there is compatibility issue with font-awesome icons. It's not supported by all browsers. You have to be carefull to using font-awesome icons font.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 18. Isnt it compatible with that as well ?

Answer (score 1):

It is supported by most modern browsers.
Perhaps what is happening is that your font files are not
getting loaded.
Check network/control tab and see if the font files are not giving a 404 error.

These are the font paths:

```
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

Comment: I tried localizing the libraries and downloaded the entire package and used the css file from it. Can you direct me what all files i shall include in the html file to make it work , which are abailable in the package.

Comment: The font folder from the package has to placed side by side to your css folder (if it's the folder your fontawesome.css is in) or your have to change the paths in the css file. The only file to include to get fontawesome support is the css file.

Comment: @meistermeier Thanks , Its Working very well now. Any other tips or tricks with Font-Awesome are welcomed. I am new at this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have another font overriding your icon font. Search your CSS to see if there is another `font-family:OtherFont!important;`.

Otherwise explicitly specify your `i.fa` tags (which are used by Font-awesome to create the font) to

```
i.fa{ 
    font-family:FontAwesome!important; 
}
```

Worked great for me.